# Adding a column to a DataGrid after the ItemSource is set / adding a field to every row of a DataGrid after the ItemSource is set

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So...
I have a `Class` with the following properties:

```
 public class TblCity
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int CountryId { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a `DataGrid` whose `ItemsSource` is set to a generic list of 
the same class ( `List<TblCity>` )
All works good and all, the `DataGrid` automatically generates the columns according to the public properties in the `Class`,
This is where my brain gives up:
I want to add a `CheckBox` to every row of the datagrid.
ambitious isn't it?

What I can't afford: Adding a `CheckBox` as a property the `Class`es 
Or creating a copy `Class` that Derives from the original, and has an extra `CheckBox`
(There are many of them. too many.)

What I have Tried: this abomination:

```
class DataGridModel<T> : T
    {
        public CheckBox checkBox { get; set; }
    }
```

Which as you might know, Does not work.

Sorry if this is a dumb question to unreachable levels of idiocy. I'm still learning.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a boolean field to the class? After that, from where you want to change that field with your checkbox, just write some code to change the boolean field with the checkbox. This seems reasonable?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said above, I can't really meddle with the class itself. The Classes are DataModels, changing them would make serializing and deserializing pretty difficult. Thanks for your answer though!